# How to hide admin registration button if admin user exist

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm making a small flask application that requires the first user registration after installation to be an admin user, but after that admin user is created the "register" button is then hidden.

Im really not to sure where to start with this as I currently have a "register" button on the logged out screen but Im not sure how to go about hiding this after the initial admin account has been created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine that it is an admin user.? Is there any particular parameter? and if the user is stored in database?

Comment: So the first registration after being installed for the first time will always be the admin user, that admin user will provide a (username, password) then have their details stored in a postgres DB which i use SQLAlchemy to talk to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply count the number of user in user table. If it is zero then you can show the register button else it will be hidden.

```
userCount = db.session.execute('select count(id) as c from user').scalar()
return render_template('register.html', userCount=userCount)
```

Check what is the value of userCount if its null(0) or not:

```
{% if userCount == 0 %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('register')}}">register</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for the help :)